# shouldStartLoadWithRequest equivalent in WebKit framework?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webkit

I'm trying to looking for an equivalent implement of `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` in the WebKit framework (on Mac).

I looked through `WebUIDelegate` & `WebFrameLoadDelegate` but did not find anything useful.

Any help is very much appreciated =). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:` and other related `WebPolicyDelegate` methods do the same thing.

If you do `[listener use]` in this method, it's like `return YES` in iOS. And vice versa: do nothing to return NO.

Answer (score -1):

Oh well I overlooked the docs. Just in case anyone has the same problem, it's `webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:`

Comment: This methods are very different. The 'webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:' is a question and the 'webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:' is a notification.

Comment: I agree this is very different than shouldStartLoadWithRequest... shouldStartLoadWithRequest allows you to cancel the request and handle it yourself. didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame does not.